# sqlite vs realm in terms of data security from hackers

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, xamarin.android, realm

I am a mobile developer using xamarin.android and my task sooner or later is to make applications for clients which are commonly from banks.
I am currently developing with realm(beginner) for app that doesn't require security issues.

What I want to know is, which one does give more secured local database from all types of hackers if I will make an app and let's say that... it is for a bank mobile system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Realm and SQLite use files stored in your app's private directory within the internal storage. This is safe enough for most cases since no app apart from yours is allowed to access it.

However, you have to take account on rooted devices. With those, users can navigate the whole filesystem with ease, including your app's private directory.

Given this, our best bet relies on data encryption.

[Realm supports AES-256 encryption](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#encryption) if you asked for it:

```
byte[] key = new byte[64];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(key);
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
  .encryptionKey(key)
  .build();

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

Accessing Realm with those will transparently encrypt/decrypt any data that is persisted to disk. Which improves security without needing extra effort from your side as the developer.

[This project](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/encryptionExample) demoes how you can make use of Realm's encryption feature.

As for SQLite… I haven't found anything yet. Maybe your best bet is to manually do the encryption/decryption yourself.

Comment: It seems that it is not really secured storage at all unless otherwise encrypted :) Well thanks for your great explanation and made me feel good about realm. I think I don't need to jump to sqlite in the future since realm has it's own encryption . Cheers!!!

Comment: I can add up that using an open-source os like android you alway facing lack of security, therefore the best practice is moving all sensitive informations to a cloud or web-service.

Comment: Well said, Mohsen. It is true; OSS is truly a double-edged sword. If you want to be truly safe then a proper backend would still be the best solution currently out there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [sqlicipher android](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher) ?

Comment: nope :) but let me look for it . thanks for the info !